# Как получить children из this (не jQuery)

Tags: javascript

Как получить детей из this.(не jQuery)
this.????.classList.add('is_active');

Comment: А что у вас this?

Comment: this это один из несколько блоков на который нажал user

Comment: Ну собственно `this.children` это и есть дети. Только это NodeList и никакого classList у него нет, придётся писать цикл

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо всё получилось))

Comment: @AlexeyTen ответом оформите?